# Discord.js - Embed links? V12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm new to discord.js and js overall so I'm curious on how my links don't appear embedded?

I want them to appear like this https://prnt.sc/twcqv5 instead of just my embed with out that showing

Input: https://prnt.sc/twcvzo

Output: https://prnt.sc/twcw23

```
exports.run = async(client, message, args) => {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission(['ADMINISTRATOR'])) return message.reply("You cant use that")
    else {
        await message.delete()
        let text = message.content.substring(6);
        if (!text) return message.reply(`Please provide **text** after the command to embed`)

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('BLACK')
            .setAuthor('Syprant Gaming')
            .setDescription(`${text}`)

        try {
            message.channel.send(embed);
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please could you add some example input and an output screenshot.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the problem is. How does your output differ from your example?

Comment: @DaemonBeast It doesn't add the embed of the actual links, how I want it to appear https://prnt.sc/twcqv5

Comment: Do you mean the individual embeds for each social media platform? If so, you'll have to do that yourself, or get another bot to do it.

Comment: @DaemonBeast Ah, there's actually no way to do it by adding in a piece of code?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. From your example screenshot, it seems that there are other bots detecting the links and displaying the embeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put link preview with links inside an embed.

If you want to have URL redirection and stuff like that, you can only use these methods:

You can first of all format links in a description with `[Link name](https://your-url.com)`.

For the example you sent, you need to check these methods:

`.setAuthor(name, iconURL, url)` -> Put your link instead of 'url'. Author line is at the top of the embed.

`.setURL(url)` -> Put your link instead of 'url'.